# UIBezierPath segment join results in gaps

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I'm using `[SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath...]`, but no matter which options I set for line join, flatness, or miterLimit, I'm getting gaps when the line is drawn. Why is this happening?

[image]

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 49.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(273.5, 49.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(273.5, 116.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(273.5, 49.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(322.5, 82.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(287.5, 222.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(224.5, 150.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(287.5, 222.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(227.5, 294.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(287.5, 222.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(351.5, 316.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 255.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(103.5, 272.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(43.5, 255.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 181.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(43.5, 255.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-38.5, 221.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(171.5, 181.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(125.5, 141.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(171.5, 164.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(123.5, 203.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(171.5, 198.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(160.5, 225.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(54.5, 222.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(86.5, 181.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(54.5, 222.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(227.5, 255.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(54.5, 222.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(210.5, 277.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(227.5, 181.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(244.5, 233.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(227.5, 181.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(227.5, 116.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(227.5, 181.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(206.5, 142.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(227.5, 88.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(248.5, 90.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(227.5, 88.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 88.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 49.5)];
[bezierPath closePath];

CGFloat scale = 4;
[bezierPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)];
```

Comment: I am seeing a perfect J - are you sure you are not drawing something else on top of the curves?

Comment: Yup. I've zoomed in on the gap between the segments for this picture. Not all segments have a gap, but most do. I tried changing line join behavior to no avail, and adjusting "scale" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/lineWidth)

> A line width larger than 2.0 may cause rendering artifacts in the
>   final rendered image. The default value is 1.0.

Changing the linewidth might help. Using UIKIT however does not cause any defects for sure. I wonder if you can switch to that.

Another interesting read :
http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

Comment: It was the line width. To produce the image I wanted without artifacts would take two SKShapeNodes overlayed on top of one another to create an edge effect.